# Unrecognized escape sequence error in AJAX parmeter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to populate a jQuery data table using AJAX. The parameter I am passing to web service is a file path and I keep getting unrecognized escape sequence error. I tried to escape the some characters to no avail:

```
Unrecognized escape sequence. (15): { \\u0027Path\\u0027: \\u0027C:\\\\TEMP\\\\DEV\\\\IDC\\\\2391\\\\GBS_IDC_WS_20190508.log\\u0027}\
```

This is the Submit button click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (ev) {
    var wsUrl = "services/lv.asmx/ProcessLogFile";
    var wsParams = "{ 'Path': '" + escapeHtml(logPath) + "'}";
    // var wsParams = '{ "Path": "' + logPath + '"}';
    populateTable(wsUrl, wsParams, tblContacts);
    return false;
});

function populateTable(ws_url, parameters, table) {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ws_url,
        cache: false,
        data: parameters,
    }).done(function (result) {
        table.clear().draw();
        if (!result || result.d === "") {
        }
        else {
            jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);
            table.rows.add(jResult).draw();
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

This is the script I found online to escape some characters:

```
var entityMap = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    '/': '&#x2F;',
    '`': '&#x60;',
    '=': '&#x3D;'
};

function escapeHtml (string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
    });
}
```

Comment: `var wsParams = { Path: escapeHtml(logPath)};`

Comment: New error after using your suggestion: "Invalid JSON primitive: Path."

Comment: Mohamed, please change your comment to answer and I will mark it as answer even though I had to use JSON.stringify to make it work. However, my code did not work, even with JSON.stringify, before I used your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to replace the following line in function populateTable(ws_url, parameters, table), following Mohammad's suggestion as well:

```
data: parameters,
```

with:

```
data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
```

So, the updated (partial) methods are:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (ev) {
    var wsUrl = "services/lv.asmx/ProcessLogFile";
    var wsParams = { Path: escapeHtml(logPath) };
    populateTable(wsUrl, wsParams, tblContacts);
    return false;
});

function populateTable(ws_url, parameters, table) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ws_url,
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    }).done(function (result) {...}
```